# Taking User Input. Python GUI

Tags: python-3.x

I'm in the process of making a python GUI calculator. I've been coding for no more than 3-4 week so my knowledge is limited. Anyway i want to make a pop up window that takes input from the user(Enter number, press a button to save that number in a variable).
That should be done twice(in order to add, subtract,... 2 numbers). Then i'll make another pop-up window saying: "The result is:(result)"
I know how to make an entry widget so my question is how do i make a button to save the user's input to a variable?

Comment: Show us the code you have tried, and tell us what happened.

Comment: @Angel: please include a [Minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) version of the relevant code in the question itself, Please don't link to external resources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I highly recommend using a module called tkinter for new coders wanting to learn GUI programming in python. A complete tutorial can be found here:
http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/

However, creating a calculator with tkinter is pretty easy. Before you start you should think of what type of calculator you want to make, one with buttons or user input. Since you are a beginner let's do the user input method.

First if you cannot import tkinter without striking and error, head over to command prompt and write:

```
pip install tkinter
```

First things first we need to create the popup window:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.mainloop()
```

Now we need to create and Entry widget:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
User_input = Entry()
User_input.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Now you will get an Entry where you will write your math problem.

Many people get confused at this stage because when they call the .get() function it doesn't work. This is because .get() makes a string. So in order to get an int you use

```
user_problem  = int(User_input.get())
```

Then you use the int (numbers) the user wrote and solve them.

When using the button method assign a command callback to each button.

Comment: Nice detailed answer. I'm sure it will help someone.